# Smooth hazard function at given knots in R

Tags: r, survival, kernel-smoothing, hazard, functional-data-analysis

Is there a way to obtain a smooth estimate of the hazard function at specific x coordinates in R? My problem is related to functional data analysis where I have a number of hazard function estimates (data for different periods) so the functions need to be smooth but the knots need to be placed at the same points (these will be some quantiles).

Comment: You talk about needing smoothness, but how would you feel about (possibly spurious) oscillations in the fitted (spline) function? Do you have shape or monotonicity constraints?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would like a smooth estimate of the log-hazard function because functional data analysis requires this. Since the estimate is non-parametric, I do not have any shape/monotonicity constraints for the function itself. Actually I have used this log-hazard transformation to avoid the monotonicity constraint in the c.d.f. which I am trying to predict.

Comment: Without any constraints, the MLE estimator for the hazard will be degenerate. So you will need to apply some sort of constraint to get anywhere (even if it's a less direct constraint, such as using a spline based method).

Comment: I am sorry but I am not following probably because of my limited statistical knowledge. I have successfully used muhaz or bshazard packages to obtain smooth hazard functions in R without explicitly enforcing any specific constraints (I presume the functions internally take care of such constraints). My issue is that I cannot pre-select the knots which should be the same over all hazard functions (for the same population over different periods). This is the step I need to continue with the functional data analysis.